# Convert datetime c++ struct (received as bytes) to c# datetime instance

Tags: c#, c++, bit-shift

So i am working on replacing a legacy app that was written in c++ and i have hit a small issue in mapping a struct used in network communications to c#.  Basically the other end on the tcp connection uses the following struct to write dates and i have no idea how to convert the bytes generated by serialising that struct to a c# datetime. Most of it is easy till you get to the "millis" and "second" which are made up of 10 bits and 6 bits respectively so that the 2 bytes is shared between them.  I assume you solve this with bit-shifting to read and write the values to a byte array but i have no experience with this.

```
typedef struct DATE_TIME
{
    USHORT  year;
    UCHAR   month;
    UCHAR   day;
    UCHAR   hour;
    UCHAR   minute;
    USHORT  millis : 10;
    USHORT  second : 6;
}
```

Code for current attempt to read

```
ushort Year = br.ReadUInt16();
byte Month = br.ReadByte();
byte Day = br.ReadByte();
byte Hour = br.ReadByte();
byte Minute = br.ReadByte();

ushort secAndMillSec = br.ReadUInt16();
ushort Milliseconds = (ushort)(secAndMillSec >> 6);
ushort Seconds = (ushort)((ushort)(secAndMillSec << 12)>>12);
```

Code for my first try at a write

```
 bw.Write(Year);
 bw.Write(Month);
 bw.Write(Day);
 bw.Write(Hour);
 bw.Write(Minute);

 ushort secAndMillSec = (ushort)(Milliseconds << 6);
 secAndMillSec = (ushort)(secAndMillSec + Seconds);
 bw.Write(secAndMillSec);
```

Again does it look right?  So far all the test data i can run it against is empty dates so i am having issues testing myself

Comment: How do you receive the data? Is it a stream or byte array?

Comment: @MD.Unicorn as a stream but i have a BinaryReader/BinaryWriter on the stream so i can get them in parts for as a byte array.  At the min i am playing with extracting them all individually apart from second and milli which i get as a ushort then trying to bit shift them into separate fields

Comment: @MD.Unicorn put the first cut of the code at the bottom of my original question

Comment: millis = combined & 0x3ff;  seconds = combined >> 10;

Comment: You are doing well except for the bit manipulations. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit fields are not portable across compilers but we can assume that these two fields are in two consequent bytes.

I assume you are receiving a stream from the network, and you are at the point of reading the datetime.

```
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(networkStream);
int year = reader.ReadUInt16();
int month = reader.ReadByte();
int day = reader.ReadByte();
int hour = reader.ReadByte();
int minute = reader.ReadByte();
int ms = reader.ReadUInt16();
int second = ms >> 10;
int millist = ms & 1023;
DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millis);
```

Comment: ok thanks i will try a few simple tests and if looks good go with this implementation till i get real data i can use it on

Comment: would it make a difference if i am using ushort and byte data types instead of int.  both milli and second are ushort in my code

Comment: just to be clear the order of the fields in the struct will be the order of bits and bytes in incoming stream so milli bits before second bits

Comment: @Seer No that doesn't make a difference. About the order of bits, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If the reading works (which means the assumptions are correct, writing would be `writer.WriteUInt16((ushort)((second << 10) & millis))`

Comment: sorry just to be clear.  The struct i included at the start is the struct the legacy code is using and sending from memory so its order should be bit order right? This looks like it would create the correct ushort `ushort joint = (ushort)((milli << 6) + seconds);`. Checked the bits generated in a viewer and it looks right but your reader reads them out wrong

Comment: @Seer So are you getting the desired result from what you tried? My code is based on what [Visual C++ do about bit fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe(v=vs.110).aspx). Other compiler my be different.

Comment: Updated post / question again with something that looks like it works byte wise but still a little worried as the byte/bit order looks right to me but you seem to think it should be opposite i think? I hate not having data for the field to check it with.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14379/discussion-between-seer-and-md-unicorn)

Answer (score 0):

Seer. I was working on a similar project to. What i did was convert the date time to a Json objet then send it to c# as bytes and then from C# i read the bytes as Json. I prefer you use Json to communicate between c++ and C#.

Comment: can't as the other end is an external legacy system as well :(

Comment: There should other ways like @MD.Unicorn stated, but in case if nothing goes write in your scenario ty this solution ->. Since u have full control in ur c# app make only the communication TCP receiving part in C++ and bind it to the listening socket of ur C# app. In this case u can handle all data not only date time. because you can retrieve the value as it is in C++ and then send it to the C# in anyformat